# Custom PNG cursor - edges are not smooth

Tags: java

I wanted to create a custom cursor. Instead of the default one I tried to set this: [image], but the final effect was terrible. The edges were black and jagged:

[image]

, exactly like in this [applet](http://java-elrincondetucasa.blogspot.com/2010/07/cursor-personalizado.html) at the bootom.

The code is as follows:

```
final Image customCursor = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\my_name\\Desktop\\apple.png").getImage();
final Point hotspot = new Point(0, 0);
final String name = "Cursor";

this.setCursor(getToolkit().createCustomCursor(customCursor, hotspot, name));
```

Is there any workaround to get PNG cursor with smooth edges? It seems unbelievable that there is still such a bug in Java.

Comment: *"but the final effect was terrible."*   Got a screenshot of the final effect, for comparison?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson Here you go.

Comment: (tilts head)  I see what you mean.  That is horrid.

Comment: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4842475

Comment: As a simple suggestion: Maybe you can edit that PNG picture of yours so that its alpha channel transparent region is "clean"...I have checked with mine and it works fine (it doesn't show such artifacts)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to load it as BufferedImage and then doing an `ImageIcon(yourBufferedImage)' …?